# Where should I look to rent time on a router table?

Tags: woodworking, contractors, rental

I have a woodworking project which requires a CNC router table.  It would need a decent sized table for the 36" x 28" panels.  Somebody that spends thousands of dollars on one of these machines must do jobs for other people or rent their expertise and time on it.

What should I be searching for?  Is there a specific name for this service or a type of facility which does small jobs?  I live in Maine and there doesn't appear to be much for groups equipped with high-end tools, such as hackerspaces or woodworking groups.

Comment: This question might be off topic, as it's not exactly home improvement or DIY. It may also be too localized, as your looking for a place to cut your panels in *X city*, Maine (not sure that could help folks in India, for example).

Comment: This isn't necessarily a localized question.  This is a question on how to find locations that may that offer but don't advertise this particular service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [CNC Zone](http://www.cnczone.com) has an area for matching up people who need CNC work done.

You can also look in your yellow pages for people who make wooden signs as these are commonly made by CNC.

Comment: Thank you!  I found a local furniture maker who does CNC work on the side.

Answer (score 3):

[100kGarages.com](http://www.100kgarages.com/) is a community of workshops with digital fabrication equipment (ShopBots, etc).

Comment: This is an excellent resource too!  There is a single entry for Maine which I'm looking into.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if this is an option here, but do you have kids that are in school?  Do they have a woodshop in their school?  If so, ask if you could use one at the school.  Most decent schools have a fairly good woodshop for kids to take elective woodworking classes.  Even if you dont have kids, if you have a highschool that is near you, go talk to the woodshop teacher and see if they will let you use their tools.  Worth a shot if you cannot find anything else.

Comment: A community college or vocational school might also be an option.